# Background image not set if using RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, background, android-relativelayout

I have a problem setting the background IMAGE for the RelativeLayout. I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, that the background image is shown in the emulator, but not on the phone itself. It is a Galaxy S4. Any suggestions?

Comment: any exceptions in your logcat?

Comment: No exceptions. The app runs normally but no background is set. Instead it is empty.

Comment: DO you have any background image in layout-xxhdp? Assuming you have different background image for different layouts

Comment: @Tarun This solved my problem, but why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783793/background-image-not-set-if-using-relativelayout/18783876?noredirect=1#comment27695454_18783876

Comment: check if you have duplicates of that layout in different folders

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make Height and Width fill_parent:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: Have you put background.png in that 5 folders, Drawable-ldpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-xhdpi, Drawable=xxhdpi?

Comment: if the background.png is setted in one folder of drawables , it should be displayed even if the right drawable image is not setted for the right resolution of the S4 ( xxhdpi). it's strange , the code is correct, try to change the `fill_parent`( **deprecated in API Level 8** )with `match_parent` , and try to change the background image with another one to see if it is a problem about the file itselfs, and if you have other devices , try it out and tell us the result

Comment: @pratik: THANK YOU! That solved my problem. But why do I have to put it in all folders???

Comment: Because Android have lots of different sizes devices in market, to support all the screen android have decided that if you want to support all the screens or to support some bigger screen is resolution then we need to put one image in all the folders with different sizes, Android will automatically get that Image from that 4 folders as per the device resolution.

Comment: If problem is solved then please accept the answer and upvote it. So other can use this answer.

Comment: @pratik : if he set just on Image in `res/drawable-hdpi/` for example , the system will detect the resolution of the device, which is `xxhdpi`, and then he will search for the `background.png` file in that folder, if it exists , so it will be displayed, and if not, the system will search in other folders of drawables ( `res/drawable`, `res/drawable-ldpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi` and `res/drawable/xhdpi`) , and if he found the `background.png` file in one of those folders , it will be displayed even if the size of the image is not the right one for xxhdpi.

Comment: Ya Exactly, but when device size is too larger and image is too smaller at that time some device can create problem. One solution for this is, create maximum size image as per Android Guidelines, and put it in Drawable folder, because larger Image can become smaller but not vice versa.

Comment: i am not against  guide lines about how to support multiples screen size and resolutions ;) , and the problem i think is the opposite, the problem will be in the case when you try to load a large Image in a device with small resolution ( it will generate `OutOfMemoryException` ) , otherwhise, if you are loading a small image in a device with big resolution , it will not be a problem, the problem is that the image will "pixeled" which is not good for the UI of the app (y)

Comment: His problem , not mine :D

Comment: but what if the background image is to be fetched from server. In that case you cannot put images in drawable folder. I am stuck in this issue. Background image not set though images from server is properly fetched.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

change this,add width and height in dp's then view in mobile
like:

```
 android:layout_width="300dp"
 android:layout_height="300dp"
```

create drawable folder in res folder copy paste your all images in that folder.then you can see all images in all resolutions and in all devices.

Comment: @MarcelHöll create drawable folder in res folder copy paste your all images in that folder.then you can see all images in all resolutions and in all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with match_parent, because fill_parent is deprecated on API level 8+.
Also check in which package you've inserted the background drawable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pratik solve my problem within this comment:

[Background image not set if using RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783793/background-image-not-set-if-using-relativelayout/18783876?noredirect=1#comment27695454_18783876)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Place your images in drawable-xxhdpi. Android scales up/down the image for high/low resolution devices. It efficiently scales down the image but while scaling up it messes with memory issues. When you keep your image assets in high res drawable folder (i.e drawbale-xxhdpi), it doesn't need to scale them up. Hope this helps.